# Redux-persist | states are undefined when persistor.pruge is deleted

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-saga, redux-persist

I have an app which load data from the server and saves them in the state. I need to store a few of these states to decrease the load from the server. But when i commented my persistor.purge() in my configureStore app does not startups anymore!

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import hardSet from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/hardSet';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import reducers from '../reducers';
import rootSaga from './sagas';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleware = [sagaMiddleware];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  middleware.push(logger);
}

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'rootApp',
  storage,
  stateReconciler: hardSet,
};


const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  const persistor = persistStore(store);
  // persistor.purge();
  return { store, persistor };
};
```

**index.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
import configureStore from './config/configureStore';

const { store, persistor } = configureStore();
const onBeforeLift = () => {
  // take some action before the gate lifts
};

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} onBeforeLift={onBeforeLift} persistor={persistor}>
      <MainStack />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

**The error:**

[image: screenshot from 2018-01-24 16-36-36]

Comment: Have you tried passing in the initial state to the [createStore()](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md)?

Comment: @epikhighs Not yet. The problem is the app was working!